# Adding time stamp to Video

Tags: video, timestamp, directshow

I am working on an application where I am capturing a full HD Video from a framegrabber card and saving it to a file on disk. I am using Diretshow interfaces to capture the video stream, encode it and then using AVI Mux filter I am saving it to the disk.

Now I also want to add the timestamp(time when video was captured) to the video file, so that timestamp is visible on the top of video when user plays the video file later. And user should be able to play it any popular players(VLC, Windows media player etc.). Can anyone help me with possible methods for achieving this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own filter for this that inherits from CTransInPlaceFilter. Override the Transform method and in it you can write the time stamp on top of the Bitmap using GDI+.

You would have to connect this filter in the appropriate position in the graph i.e. somewhere where the media type is RGB.

EDIT:
Here's some sample code ripped from a filter of mine for writing text on an RGB frame.
Hopefully that should get you started:

```
#include <Gdiplus.h>
...
using namespace Gdiplus;

HRESULT UtilityFilter::Transform(IMediaSample *pSample)
{
  ...
  std::string sText = ...
  return drawTextOntoFrame(sText, pSample); 
}

HRESULT UtilityFilter::drawTextOntoFrame(const std::string& sText, IMediaSample *pSample)
{
  // get image properties
  AM_MEDIA_TYPE mt;
  HRESULT hr = InputPin()->ConnectionMediaType(&mt);
  if (FAILED(hr))
  {
    return hr;
  }
  ASSERT(mt.formattype == FORMAT_VideoInfo);
  BITMAPINFOHEADER *pbmi = HEADER(mt.pbFormat);

  // Get image buffer
  BYTE *pBuffer(NULL);
  hr = pSample->GetPointer(&pBuffer);
  if (FAILED(hr))
  {
    return hr;
  }

  wchar_t* wsText = StringUtil::stlToWide(sText);

  BITMAPINFO bitmapInfo;
  bitmapInfo.bmiHeader = *pbmi;

  Bitmap bm(&bitmapInfo, (void*)pBuffer);
  Graphics* pGraphics = Graphics::FromImage(&bm);

  // Initialize font
  Font myFont(L"Arial", 16);
  //RectF layoutRect(0.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f, 50.0f);
  RectF layoutRect(m_uiX, m_uiY, 350.0f, 50.0f);
  StringFormat format;
  format.SetAlignment(StringAlignmentNear);
  SolidBrush blackBrush(Color(255, 0, 0, 0));
  SolidBrush greenBrush(Color(255, 0, 255, 0));

  // Draw string
  pGraphics->DrawString(
    wsText,
    sText.length(),
    &myFont,
    layoutRect,
    &format,
    &greenBrush);

  delete[] wsText;
  delete pGraphics;
  return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ralf. Do you think using srt will be feasible considering timestamp will be updated every second or half a second ?

Comment: @EagleEye Not sure what you mean by "srt". From a performance perspective I've used this approach to write time stamps onto a frame and had no issues.

Comment: By srt, I meant I would store the srt file containing the timestamp values for evry second and user can load this srt as subtitles file in any player, but I dont know if this will work. I tried your method and I have developed the CTransInPlaceFilter and I am getting frames in YUV2 format in transform function and now I dont know how to add text onto it using GDI+. I couldnot find any reference material for it. Can you help me with where to begin on using GDI+ to add text onto it.

Comment: @EagleEye Subtitles is a different story: this approach would embed the time stamp into the actual video: this time stamp would not be removable. In retrospect, this doesn't sound like the right solution for you. However looks like there is no native support in DS and WMP: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/0194e6ab-e4d4-4dbe-a7e4-2bcdd3580ab6 Also, the I suspect the WMP solution will differ from the VLC one...

Comment: Hey Ralf thanks for your reply. I too wasn't sure if srt was such a good idea. I am sorry in my previous comment I misspelled format type. It's actually YUY2 format. I dont want to add overhead of conversion from YUY2 to RGB32. I can't seem to find how to add bitmap to YUY2 image frame. Can you help me with where to begin.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't give any opinion on srt, you would have to decide which approach works for you. WRT to the YUY2 input format: I don't know if GDI can handle that. If you do decide to embed the time stamp into the video, I would convert to RGB first by means of a color converter. Then draw on the time stamp in the trans in place, and then encode it, etc... I'll update my answer with an example of how to write onto a RGB frame.

Comment: You can prob accomplish the YUY2 to RGB conversion by only accepting, say RGB24 in your transinplace filter. DS *should* then automatocally insert some YUY2RGB filter before your transinplace, provided that your system has the required filter. That should be quick enough to test: Modify the accepted types of your transinplace, build a graph in graphedit and try to connect your capture to the transinplace. If all is well, DS will have inserted the required CC filter.